# Integral of $g(x)=1/x$

Tags: real-analysis

Let the function:
$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
1/x & x\neq0 \\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}
$$ 
Let $g^+(x)$ be the positive part of $g$ and $g^-(x)$ the negative part. Then suppose that $K\in\mathbb{R}<+\infty$
$$
\int_{-K}^K g^+(x)dx=\int_0^K g(x)=+\infty.\quad\int_{-K}^K g^-(x)dx=\int_{-K}^0 (-g(x))dx=+\infty
$$
Thus the integral of $g$ is not defined. But $g$ is an odd function, following that:
$$
g(-x)=-g(x)\implies \int_{-K}^K g(x)dx=0
$$
Which is correct?

Comment: Just because the integrand is odd doesn't mean the integral is zero (it has to be *defined* in order to be zero), but it does mean the "principal value" is zero.

Comment: When the first integral is written, its argument $g^+(x)$ is not defined in $-K$, since the function covers only the positive line of $\mathbb{R}$, or $\mathcal{D}:(0,+\infty)$

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by $\int_{-K}^K g(x)dx$. If it's the usual Riemann or Lebesgue integral, then it's not integrable; however, this notation may in some contexts refer to the [Cauchy Principal Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), which is the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ of integrals omitting $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ from the domain, which is zero since the function is odd.